# p tag hover over to show hidden text will change the position of next element

Tags: html, css

I have a question about the property of `text-overflow`, here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGqnj/836/)

What I want to do is when I hover over the `p` tag, it will show me the remaining text, like it does in the demo, and I **do not** want the positions of `<span>` be changed, which means I do not want `<span>` being pushed back, it is ok if `<span>`is covered by the text when I hovering over.

I used `position:absolute` for `<span>` but it seems like a bad [practice](http://jsfiddle.net/KGqnj/837/)

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/KGqnj/841/

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if the site went down in the future! (It would be *terrible,* we know.) Also, some people are behind corporate firewalls that forbid the use of code sharing websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: absolute` is the way to got, but then you need a wrapping element (DIV) which has `position: relative` (seperately for each line). Add the appropriate position settings as in my snippet below. To cover the `span`, use a `z-index: -1` (in combination with `position: absolute`) to let it go *under*  the expanding `p` element.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 0;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 210px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

p:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p class='p'>this is a simple paragraph that is meant to be nice and easy to type which</p>
  <span>test</span>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <p class='p'>this is a simple paragraph that is meant to be nice and easy to type whichthis is a simple paragraph that is meant to be nice and easy to type which </p>
  <span>test</span>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <p class='p'>this is a simple paragraph that is h</p>
  <span>test</span>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <p class='p'>this is a simple paragraph that is meant to be nice and this is a simple paragraph that is meant to be nice and easy to type whichh</p>
  <span>test</span>
</div>
```